# jitterbit load source dynamically

Tags: jitterbit

I'm trying to do a jitterbit formatting to be executed automatically, but I need to load several files from diferent directories  as source file, anyone know if this is possible, because I've been searching but seems like the source is always fixed

Answer (score 0):

Use a script task before the source and set a variable like `$filedirectory` and use that the source task.

Then in the source you can use `[filedirectory]` for the directory path. If you want the test connection to still work provide a default value like `[filedirectory{\\server\share}]`

Use regular expressions in the source file name or something like `*.xml` if you want to process multiple files.

For more refer official documentation:
http://support.jitterbit.com/documentation/Using-File-Type-Sources-and-Targets